# Function return changing its input

Tags: function, fortran

I have a fortran function to change the case of a string

```
Function chcase (a) Result (b)
Character (Len=:), Allocatable :: b
Character (Len=*), Intent (In) :: a

Create string s, upper case of string a 
...
b = Trim (s)

End Function chcase
```

I want to be able to change the case using the same string by calling

```
s = chcase (s)
```

Should I better use

```
Character (Len=*), Intent (InOut) :: a
```

Using Intent (In) I still get correct result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the language specification, for the syntax `s = chcase(s)`, the evaluation of the function reference `chcase(s)` is completed before the resulting value is assigned to `s`.

The appropriate INTENT specification to use is the one that reflects the nature of the dummy argument during the lifetime of execution of the relevant procedure.  That is likely `INTENT(IN)` for this case, if the elided contents of the `chcase` function are sensible.

By the time the assignment happens, the intent specification of the dummy argument of the function is irrelevant - the function has completed execution and the dummy argument no longer exists.

(Fortran 77 had restrictions in terms of self assignment to character variables, but these are not relevant today - Fortran 77 also did not have INTENT specifications or ALLOCATABLE function results.)